# Creating preload link tag in a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a custom shortcode in a snippet from Plugin CodeSnippets.
This shortcode insert a picture and I'd like to insert the preload tag

```
<link rel="prelaod" as="image" href="path/to/my/image.webp">
```

But it seems I can't add action to wp_head hook...

As the

```
add_action('wp_head', function() { echo '<link rel="prelaod" as="image" href="path/to/my/image.webp">'; });
```

doesn't seem to work (add_action function has no effect if it's used inside my shortcode fuction) I've tried to use a global array to save the href but... it seems I don't know how to modify the global scope value...

Let's simplify my current code :

```
global $preloading_data;
$preloading_data = array('href' => 'HREF', 'imagesrcset' => 'SRCSET', 'imagesizes' => 'SIZES');

add_shortcode( 'MH_FeaturedProduct', 
function() use ($preloading_data)
{
    global $preloading_data;
    $out = "";
// creating the html code to be inserted...
    $preloading_data['href'] = "path/to/my/image.webp";
    $preloading_data['imagesrcset'] = $srcset;
    $preloading_data['imagesizes'] = $sizes;
// using add_action('wp_head', function(){ echo $my_preload_tag; } ) has no effect here
// that's why I had to create global array
    return $out;
});
global $preloading_data;
                
add_action('wp_head',
function() use ($preloading_data)
{
    global $preloading_data;
    echo '<link rel="preload" as="image" fetchpriority="high" href="'.$preloading_data['href'].'" imagesrcset="'.$preloading_data['imagesrcset'].'" imagesizes="'.$preloading_data['imagesizes'].'">';
// in this function $preloading_data seems not hving been modified...
// because the insert tag is <link rel="preload" as="image" fetchpriority="high" href="HREF" imagesrcset="SRCSET" imagesizes="SIZES">
});
```

Comment: You're too late. When the shortcode runs, wp_head already processed. Think twice how wise it is to have this functionality in a shortcode... .

Comment: It's true that I hadn't thought about the processing sequence...
So, how can I insert a preload tag in my header for thé image used in thé shortcode?

Comment: Well I think that is called a _[hen-and-egg problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg)_. As you don't know if the shortcode and with which attributes is being executed (or at all), how can we insert something into the head in Wordpress? I must admit, I'm not aware if that is possible and I don't have a copy at hand to drop some of me WP mojo on it. If there is a way you know upfront a shortcode comes to action, there _might_ be a way, perhaps if you add some more clarifications to your question in this regard and reflect what you've learned since posting, more chance?

Comment: I can create a function in header that checks if the post contains the shortcode but has_shortcode function only identify WordPress built-in shortcodes...

Comment: Technically the post itself (which contains the chortcodes) must be already resolved in the head as the \<title> must be set in the head as well. Maybe there is a quick scan of the contents for the shortcode possible that is independt to core ones, e.g. registering your shortcode this early? I would give that a try as then has_shortcode might reveal yours (unchecked).

Comment: I've checked and has_shortcode does not reveal the shortcode I've created has specified in the man page...

Comment: did you register your shortcode filters/hooks before running has_shortcode() ?

Answer (score 0):

I've registered the shortcode with do_shortcode...

I've created the following code :

```
function insert_preload_tag()
{
    $post = get_post();
    $content = $post->post_content;
    if (str_contains($content, '['))
    {
        preg_match_all('/(MH_FeaturedProduct).+id="?([0-9]+)/', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        if (!empty($matches))
        {
            foreach($matches as $shortcode)
            {
// processiing the preload tag with data from $shortcode[2] which containing the id of the product to be featured
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'insert_preload_tag');
```